# How can I find an interval where $f(x)=\frac 12(x+\frac 3x)$ is contractive mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

I want to find out an interval where $f(x)=\frac12(x+\frac 3x)$ is contractive mapping.

How can I find this interval where $f(x)$ becomes contractive?

Comment: where $|f'|< 1$ Discontinuous at $x=0,$ if there is an answer with $x > 0,$ there is a mirror image with $x < 0$

Comment: I get f' equal to (x^2-3)/(2x^2), so I found out value of x such that lf'l<1 the only inequality that makes sense is x^2<1, which is not right answer..

Comment: suggest you draw a careful graph of $y = (x^2 - 3)/ (2 x^2)$  http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph including horizontal and vertical asymptotes

Comment: it is a contraction mapping over its domain, don't have to worry about $x=0$ as the function itself isn't defined. Since you ask for interval, you can take any subinterval of $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$

Comment: Pagol , http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/contraction.pdf

Comment: If you look at the second page of this pdf, why would he divide the positive interval into some (t.00) and t is value between two numbers?

Answer (score 1):

We need a constanct $k$ with $0<k<1$ and an interval $I$ such that for arbitrary $x,y\in I$ the inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|$ be verified. Let's see.
$$\frac12|(x+\frac3x)-(y+\frac 3y)|\le k|x-y|$$ implies 
$$|(x-y)(1-\frac{3}{xy})|\le2k|x-y|\Rightarrow|\frac{x-y}{|x-y|}(1-\frac {3}{xy})|\le 2k$$
 Hence $$|(1-\frac{3}{xy})|\le 2k\iff-2k\le1-\frac {3}{xy}\le2k$$
 It follows $$\frac{3}{2k+1}\le xy\le\frac{3}{1-2k}$$ 
For all $k$ such that $1-2k\ge0$, i. e. $0\le k\le\frac12$ we can choose as endpoints of the searched interval $I$ the numbers $\sqrt {\frac {3}{2k+1}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac {3}{1-2k}}$ in order to ensure that if $x,y\in I$ then $\frac {3}{2k+1}\le xy \le \frac  {3}{1-2k}$.

**Thus, for instance**, **$f(x)=\frac 12(x+\frac{3}{x})$ is contractive on $I=[\sqrt{\frac{15}{7}}, \sqrt 5]$ with  Lipschitz constant $k=\frac15$.**

Answer (score 0):

We know by mean value theorem that, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f'||x-y|$, where $|f'|=\sup_x|f'(x)|$. Note that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2x^2}$, and if $x\geq \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$ we have $|f'|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. In particular, $f$ is a contraction on $[\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2},+\infty)$.